# How to shield from electro surgical generator in close proximity?

Tags: emc

Looking for help EMI hardening a SERDES interface in close proximity to electro surgical instruments. I believe there may be tips or reference designs from existing pacemaker applications that may assist in my pursuit. Are there any examples or design resources available for this situation?

Thanks

Comment: Are your signal lines running through a catheter (or applicator) ?

Comment: SERDES has likely got wide bandwidth (or why would you need to serialize several data streams?) - pacemakers, by their slow speed nature have got low bandwidth and will be more resilient.

Comment: Signals are positioned between two catheters a worst case positioning. Instruments run parallel to signal wires.

Comment: Draw up your best idea and we can suggest improvements.